# How to wipe Macintosh OS X v10.5.8 but leave software and OS?

Tags: macos, mac, wipe

Are there any free tools to wipe the user contents of a Macintosh running OS X v10.5.8 to keep the operating system and software products installed but remove any user data for selling the computer to another party?

Comment: This won't help you solve this issue right now, but I usually take a time machine backup of any new Mac I buy, before I've done ANYTHING to it, so I can restore it back to "factory" before selling it or giving it to someone. Easier than reinstalling from scratch in most cases. Just for future reference.

Comment: +1, agree - I'd wipe it and reinstall OS X from scratch, which is probably the safest route. Takes a while though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be completely sure that all traces of your data is removed, both of the "prep for sale" guides ([here](https://gigaom.com/2011/02/25/how-to-prepare-a-used-mac-for-sale/) and [here](http://appletoolbox.com/2011/03/how-to-safely-prepare-your-mac-for-sale/)) that I came across recommended wiping your machine's drive and reinstalling OS X. The good news is that you can accomplish this without purchasing or installing any additional software - just back up your data and use **Disk Utility** to wipe the drive.

Apple Toolbox's [guide](http://appletoolbox.com/2011/03/how-to-safely-prepare-your-mac-for-sale/) recommends:

> - **Back up your data.** Using Time Machine, or another backup option, make sure your backup is current. Once you complete these steps, there
>     will be no way of retrieving anything.
> - **Boot off of your OS X disk.** To do this, insert the OS X disk that came with your machine, reboot your computer, and hold down the C
>     key while the machine is booting up. Open Disk Utility. Once your
>     machine has booted off of the disk, and you have selected your
>     preferred language, go to the Utilities menu and select Disk Utility.
>     Once Disk Utility is open, proceed to the Erase tab.
> - **Enter a name for the formatted drive.** On the Erase tab, enter a name that will be used once the drive is erased. By default, a Macʼs
>     hard drive is named “Macintosh HD.” Since you are preparing to sell
>     the machine, this is a good choice.
> - **Select the security level.** Below the name field, you will see a button that says: “Security Options.” Once selected, you will be
>     presented with a number of different options. These include: “Do Not
>     Erase Data,” “Zero Out Data,” “7-Pass Erase,” and “35-Pass Erase.” The
>     first option is essentially the same as dragging a file to (and then
>     emptying) the Trash…except that it does it for every single file on
>     the hard drive. Ultimately, however, the data still remains. The other
>     three options erase the data and write zeros over the entire hard
>     drive once, 7 times, or 35 times depending on the option you choose.
>     **For most people, the single “Zero Out Data” will be more than sufficient.** If your machine has particularly sensitive information
>     on it, such as company financials, trade secrets, or the next great
>     novel, you may want to go with the “7-Pass Erase.” This option is
>     considered secure enough to be the standard procedure for erasing US
>     Department of Defense computers. You can rest easy using this option,
>     while the “35-Pass Erase” is essentially overkill for all but the most
>     extreme cases. Once you have selected the appropriate option, click
>     the Erase button.
> - **Install OS X and reboot.**

However, the steps here will not leave your existing software in place.

If you're interested in leaving the software and OS X in place, deleting all of your data files, and use **Disk Utility** to wipe the free disk space. Steps from [Apple Support](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=DiskUtility/10.5/en/duh1010.html):

> **Erasing free disk space does not erase the other files** on your disk.
>
> - In Disk Utility, select the disk or volume in the list with the free space you want to erase.
> - Click Erase, then click the Erase Free Space button.
> - Select an option, then click Erase.

You may also want to create a new admin user, delete your old account(s), and run the Disk Utility routine to erase free space used by your account(s).

Answer (score 2):

You can go a really long way by creating a new admin user account and then using it to delete all the existing user accounts, including deleting their home directories. Then I might delete any existing network "locations" in `System Preferences -> Network`. And use Keychain Access to clear out most of the System keychain.

I guess there could still be some traces left in `/Library`, especially `/Library/Preferences` and `/Library/Logs`. And maybe `/var`, especially `/var/log`.

...Hmm. The more I think about how complicated this problem is, the less I would trust any tool to do a good job of it. I think you really need to just "nuke and repave".

Comment: Not to mention all the non-standard installers that probably leave traces all over the file system, as well as user profile data.